# Oscilloscope Probe - How to measure a sensitive circuit

Tags: analog, oscilloscope, piezo, probe

Help needed in measuring a tiny piezo actuator.

The circuit bangs the actuator with a voltage ( max 50V ), then senses the ripples after the initial actuation.

How can I measure with an oscilloscope and disturb the circuit the least.

The response frequency of the piezo is between 80-120KHz.

I am actually reversing a circuit, I just need to see the ripples on my scope.

Here's the theoretical circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnuDi7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please show us your circuit, using the built-in schematic editor. Also, discuss the frequencies of interest in the signal.

Comment: Sounds like you try to use one actuator twice - first as a speaker, then as a microphone an do the mode swap before the echo dies. Right? Unfortunately we have no idea how you drive the actuator and what it demands. Driver must be separated before you can expect to get measured anything usable. You must give more details to get something more than guesses. Of course, it's possible that someone of us has already built it and answers, but most of us haven't.

Comment: Hello @user287001,

Yes, that's almost exactly right. The circuit is already working, it's part of an assembly.

I am just looking to capture the waves, and interfere as little as possible with the actual operation of the device.

Maybe a low impedance probe or a high impedance ?

Comment: Install a 100Kohm resistor between the Piezo and the scope probe. Use two small-signal diodes (1N4454, 1N3068, etc) as overvoltage clamps to+- 5 volts. The time constant of 100K ohm and 20pF is 2 microSeconds, or about 90KHz.

Comment: Thank you very much for help, altought, I have no access to the internal circuitry, just to the piezo crystal leads.

Comment: I am not trying to make the circuit work, it's already working fine. 

I am trying to measure the ripples, without affecting the circuit.

@user287001 already made the suggestion to use a voltage follower, and I think it's the best way to go. 

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try normal 10MOhm 10:1 probes first.

There's still plenty of caveats such as collecting disturbing signals due ground loops, interfering fields and potential difference between your circuit GND and oscilloscope's GND. Impossible to guess all without seeing. You may need 2 channel measurement in difference mode to compensate some disturbances.

Your best bet is to get a local advanced oscilloscope user to help.

**ADD due comments:** The problem seemingly is that inserting any long wires in parallel with the piezo part, the pulses get distorted in an unknown way and the operation stops.

**A suggestion:** In place of your "opamp", which should be a speedy comparator with sturdy enough input for your voltages, you surely can put a voltage follower amplifier. It's output can be measured without affecting the pulses. I guess wires make a resonant circuit which creates some ringing at several megaherzes. You can see it as "no function" if there really is an opamp instead of a proper comparator.

Comment: Hello @user287001,

Thank you for taking the time to answer.

The thing is, the circuit breaks if there's a 10Mohm resistor across ( multimeter, probe ) the pins.

Using two probes without the ground clip, sound like a good idea and a great tip.

Comment: @NorbertMezei Excuse me, but 10 megaohm probe sucks only few microamperes! Which part gets broken? If the wires cause the breakage, how the circuit can stand its own wires. 2 probe measurements still need the probe GNDs to be connected to somewhere. if they float, the result is non-predictable. Good enough connection via common ground is possible.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english formulation. The wires don't break, I actually mean, the device no longer functions correctly if anything is attached to the wires.

I am looking to reduce the effects my probes have on the circuit. Maybe capacitance, impedance or inductance is going out of spec. when probes are attached.

Comment: @NorbertMezei reading again the comment I see that your circuit does not stand the extra loading that the wires make, nothing smokes, but the pulses are not right until the extra wires are taken off. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's spot on.
The **voltage follower ( unity gain buffer or isolation amplifier )**  is exactly the right thing.
Your answer is what I was looking for. Thank you .